# Calling a library from inside a helpers function in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can I load a library from inside a helper?

```
$this->load->library('name');
```

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score -6, accepted):

No.  The purpose of helpers is to "perform one specific task, with no dependence on other functions."

Quoted from CI's [helpers page](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html).

If you need to include a library inside of your helper, consider making it a library instead.

Comment: I disagree with this. CI's own url helper loads the URI class.

Comment: You can of course load a library. It is possible and I have used this ability. jimyi's speech is 100% false.

Comment: library can be loaded from inside a helper function - check http://stackoverflow.com/a/6327423/636762

Answer (score 58):

```
function sendEmail() {
     $CI =& get_instance();
     $CI->load->library('email'); // load library 
}
```

Answer (score 17):

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * URL String
 *
 * Returns the URI segments.
 *
 * @access  public
 * @return  string
 */
if ( ! function_exists('uri_string'))
{
    function uri_string()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        return $CI->uri->uri_string();
    }
}
```

Yes, of course.

I disagree with jimyi's answer. CI's own url helper loads the URI class.

Comment: I second, if you have a created a custom library you may wish to add helpers to it.